# Should we always consider how page will look without CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, w3c, semantic-markup

If yes then presentational elements would be helpful in this condition so should we use those?

```
<b>…</b> , <i>…</i>, <big>…</big>, <small>…</small>, <tt>…</tt>, <hr />
```

These are valid tags

Comment: They're also deprecated tags. Just sayin'.

Comment: If there is no CSS, then those tags will also be useless. Think about it, a `<b>...</b>` tag is just like any other tag just with the CSS style of `font-weight: bold` set on it. Every tag is *just* a tag, each tag having default styles assigned to it.

Comment: @Matchu - no one is deprecated all are valid http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/

Comment: @jitendra: Did you read the text on the presentational tags page? "b (bold), i (italic), tt (teletype), sub (subscript), sup (superscript), big, small and hr (horizontal rule) are all presentational tags. As such, their use should be avoided and CSS used instead." AKA deprecated.

Comment: If you look at the draft HTML 5 standard, `<i>`, `<b>` and `<small>` have been given a semantic meaning and are not deprecated at all.

Comment: @animuson - deprecated and "should be avoid" is different thing.

Comment: What kind of semantic meaning could tags that quite clearly mean "make me bold, make me italic, make me small" possibly have?

Comment: Try disabling CSS when at Google homepage. Clearly they never expected anyone to browse without CSS. If they don't, why should we?

Comment: @Matchu — none, but if you look at the HTML 5 draft as David suggested, they don't mean that in HTML 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The page should be marked up **semantically**, not for its presentation. If you put proper semantic markup on elements, the browser will usually apply a basic style to them by itself. You should not be concerned with how the document looks *unstyled*. If it's *unstyled*, it has no style. CSS is responsible for the style. If a user chooses to view the document without style, let it be so.

Comment: This is true, with the qualification that the unstyled page will generally give you a strong sense of how well you have marked-up the page. The entire reason for semantic markup is to make the content available (and legible!) apart from the style. The unstyled page should read like a reasonable text document. That is an argument *for* semantics, not for presentational markup.

Comment: @Eric Exactly what I was trying to say with "browser will apply style by itself", but better put. :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally a ("*normal*") user **cannot disable CSS as easy as JavaScript**.
So I would answer **NO**.

CSS is a **part of the presentation** and when the **CSS is not available we should think that the presentation is not available**. Thus the client side is **broken**.

You should not be concerned about that as you don't want to debug a client abusing the presentation.

**BUT**, if you need to support non-standard devices (old mobiles maybe) this is a valid concern. Still instead of changing the page to "*fit all sizes*", you should have **a separate page for such devices**.

---

Not sure about `tt` (I guess you can use).
But `b`, `i` should be replaced by `strong` and `em` respectively.

`big` and `small` should not be used IMO and be replaced by alternative tags depending on the **semantics**.

Comment: i'm not talking about <big> and <small> as use as a Heading. i'm asking if we use inline. like if we use <big> over <span class="big"> then without css, text will still look bold.

Comment: I am not talking about `big` and `small` to use in headings either. The question was "Should we consider how page will look with no CSS". The answer is No. And as you can see I provided explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could pretty much create an entire page using `<div>` and `<span>` tags.  That would just be messy though, and not very intuitive.  Personally, I find that the tags you list make it easier for a human to parse what the page is attempting to communicate, while also offering the benefit of making a page readable when the CSS doesn't load.

Comment: `<b>` and `<small>` do very little to communicate an HTML document's structure. I'm all for `<ul>` and `<li>` where it makes sense, since they *do* represent structure, but... no. The tags he describes are deprecated for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking if you should use tags like `<small>` so that, in the absence of CSS, what you want to be small will be small.

**No.**

The reason to consider how the page will look without CSS is to know if you are using good semantic layout. If it's usable, your HTML, which is *only* designed with semantic organization in mind, is okay. That's it. If your users, for whatever reason, don't want to support presentational things like CSS, *don't use presentational tags*.

And, really. If your users don't have CSS for whatever reason, they don't deserve to see something as bold. It's more work for you, it's not semantic, and no one will *ever* care.